# How to display two different columns in one combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to display the two different columns in one particular combobox. When I run it the `Customer ID` will display. Here is my code.

```
void GetRecords2()
{


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, firstname 
            + ',' + lastname FROM Customer";

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds, "Customer");

    cboName.DataSource = ds;
    cboName.DisplayMember = "Customer.firstname, Customer.lastname";


    cboName.ValueMember = "Customer.CustomerID";


}
```

Comment: No sure if it is even possible? What exactly do you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you already are creating a single result column containing the "combined" value. That's have the battle.

But, you need to give your column a name (notice the `AS FullName` alias):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, firstname + ',' + lastname AS FullName " +
    "FROM Customer";
```

So you can reference it later by name:

```
cboName.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

Comment: The combobox still displaying the CustomerID

Answer (score 1):

This will work. I find that binding a `Dictionary` to a `ComboBox` has much more predictable results.

My approach omits the extra `SQL` syntax, `DataSet`, and `SqlDataAdapter`.

Instead I use the `SqlDataReader` to place the desired information into a `Dictionary` and then I bind that `Dictionary` as the `DataSource` of the `Combobox`.

```
void GetRecords2()
{         
    Dictionary <int, string> myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, firstname, lastname FROM Customer";

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       myDict.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerID"]), 
            reader["firstname"].ToString() + " " + reader["lastname"].ToString());
    }

    if (myDict.Count > 0)
    {
       cboName.DataSource = new BindingSource(myDict, null);
       cboName.DisplayMember = "Value";            
       cboName.ValueMember = "Key";  
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
void GetRecords2()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, firstname 
            + ',' + lastname FullName FROM Customer";

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds, "Customer");

    cboName.DataSource = ds;
    cboName.DisplayMember = "FullName";


    cboName.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
}
```

To get selected value :

```
string customerid = cboName.SelectedValue.toString(); //CustomerID: 1
```

To get selected item

```
string fullname = cboName.SelectedItem.Text;  //FullName :  John Hawkins
```

Best Regards